HR came to me directly... what should I do
So I had been speaking with HR  about an issue but decided not to move forward as it would mean I couldn't stay in my job.  However my boss made my life miserable and I decided to leave - HR have forwarded me my bosses email and asked if there's anything they can do to make me change my mind.  My boss has created an extremely toxic work environment and bad mouths everyone to everyone including bad mouthing the owners.  There is plenty I can say to HR but the question is should I, they keep saying they don't want me to go but I just don't know whether to tell the  everything or not.  They are based in head office so don't really know what goes on in the warehouse.  Do I go all out and reveal everything or just not bother.

Please explain to us what you think you have to lose by explaining to HR, and, clean up your post.

I don't have anything to lose but it would leave bad feeling especially for the manager as he believes he is untouchable.  He literally spends his day creating mean tik toks and stirring up trouble between staff.  Part of me thinks talk to HR and let him see that he isn't untouchable but another part just thinks it's better to walk away.

1.) HR is never your friend. This fact has been stated multiple times in SE Workplace for a good reason.
There are two possibilities. They actually want you to stay along with fixing the toxic workplace issue. The second is the much more typical purpose of HR's involvement. Only you can judge which is the true reason, not someone on the internet.
HR is likely trying to cover the company's behind. If the company if large enough (more than 50 employee, less in some places in the US), they could be concerned that you would file a complaint with the appropriate goverment agency.
If your boss has been reported to HR before, then HR would be concerned about having a documented track record. This could cost the company by being on the wrong side in defending against fines and a possible lawsuit.
BE CAREFUL - they might try to get you to sign something that effectively says you left on your on volition and not due to the workplace.
If you are given documents and pressured to sign, consider getting a lawyer.
PLEASE REMBER - This is opinion, not legal advice.

"If you are given documents and pressured to sign, consider getting a lawyer." this is a good legal advice.


the question is should I ?

Since you already have resigned there is really not much of a downside to talking to HR. What do you have to lose ?
Then again: what's your goal here? Just going for a rant is not particular professional. However, if you have good documentation of what exactly has happened and can share this, it can help the people you leave behind (if you care).

they don't want me to go

Then you need to think about: "What do you want them to do for you to change your decision?". At this point you can make pretty much ask for anything: they may say yes, the may say no. But be sure that if they "yes" you are ready to say "yes" too.

Note that if HR are reaching out, I think the threshold for "ranting" is a little bit higher: "Well, you wanted to know, so I told ya!"
